# One to Many - FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I have a class Dienstbulletin with multiple properties of the same class Persoon. 
When i execute the update-database command. I get following error:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Dienstbulletin_dbo.Persoon_OgpID' on table 'Dienstbulletin' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
    public class Persoon : DefaultFields
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Naam mag niet langer zijn dan 50 karakters.")]
        public string Naam { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecteer een correct type")]
        [Required]
        public TypePersoon TypePersoon { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Boolean Actief { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Ogp")]
        public ICollection<Dienstbulletin> OgpCollection { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Obp")]
        public ICollection<Dienstbulletin> ObpCollection { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Rechercheur")]
        public ICollection<Dienstbulletin> RechercheurCollection { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Opsteller")]
        public ICollection<Dienstbulletin> OpstellerCollection { get; set; }

    }

public class Dienstbulletin : DefaultFields
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public string Datum { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ploeg")]
        [Required]
        public int PloegID { get; set; }
        public virtual Gebruiker Ploeg { get; set; }

        public int VoertuigID { get; set; }
        public virtual Voertuig Voertuig { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opsteller")]
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Opsteller")]
        public int OpstellerID { get; set; }
        public Persoon Opsteller { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OGP met dienst")]
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Ogp")]
        public int OgpID { get; set; }
        public Persoon Ogp { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "OBP met dienst")]
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Obp")]
        public int ObpID { get; set; }
        public Persoon Obp { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rechercheur met dienst")]
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Rechercheur")]
        public int RechercheurID { get; set; }
        public Persoon Rechercheur { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
        [Display(Name = "Aandachtsvestigingen")]
        public string Aandachtspunten { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
        [Display(Name = "Bijkomende opdrachten")]
        public string BijkomendeOpdrachten { get; set; }

        #region Collections
        public virtual ICollection<Opdracht> OpdrachtCollection { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }


 public class DienstbulletinAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DienstbulletinAppContext() : base("Dienstbulletin"){}
        public DbSet<Dienstbulletin> Dienstbulletin { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Voertuig> Voertuigen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Opdracht> Opdrachts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpdrachtDetail> OpdrachtDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Locatie> Locaties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gebruiker> Gebruikers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Persoon> Personen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpdrachtType> OpdrachtTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Dienstbulletin>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Obp)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.ObpID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Dienstbulletin>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Ogp)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.OgpID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Dienstbulletin>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Rechercheur)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.RechercheurID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Dienstbulletin>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Opsteller)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.OpstellerID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain what i'm a doing wrong and how i can fix this issue?

Comment: The relationship "FK_dbo.Dienstbulletin_dbo.Persoon_OgpID" is a cascade relationship, but this will apparently cause multiple cascade paths or cycles (infinite loops). You can define this relationship as non-cascading in `OnModelCreating` or use SET NULL to just clear the relevant field if the parent record is deleted.

Comment: Steven, how can i define this relationship as non cascading in On ModelCreating? In my migration class the foreign key is non cascading .ForeignKey("dbo.Persoons", t => t.ObpID, cascadeDelete: true)

Comment: Check the answer I posted. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solutions whas this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
 }
```

found on: 
https://forums.asp.net/t/2118372.aspx?Introducing+FOREIGN+KEY+constraint+FK_dbo+Customers_dbo+States_StateId+on+table+Customers+may+cause+cycles+or+multiple+cascade+paths+Specify+ON+DELETE+NO+ACTION+or+ON+UPDATE+NO+ACTION+or+modify+other+FOREIGN+KEY+constraints

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to turn off the cascade delete for a relationship using the Fluent API. Just swap `Type1` and `Type2` with the correct types.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Type1>()
        .HasOne(i => i.Type2)
        .WithMany(c => c.Type1s)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info found this solution to work https://forums.asp.net/t/2118372.aspx?Introducing+FOREIGN+KEY+constraint+FK_dbo+Customers_dbo+States_StateId+on+table+Customers+may+cause+cycles+or+multiple+cascade+paths+Specify+ON+DELETE+NO+ACTION+or+ON+UPDATE+NO+ACTION+or+modify+other+FOREIGN+KEY+constraints